# Determinant of the $n \times n$ exchange matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, hankel-matrices

I have to find the determinant of an $n \times n$ [exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix). After applying values to $n$, I found out the determinant has a periodicity of $4$ and its formula is $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$. Literature revision confirms this. However, I don't know how to reach this conclusion formally neither how to prove it.

Comment: Have you tried expansion by minors?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1664812/339790)

Comment: Swapping two rows (or columns) of a matrix changes its determinant by a factor of $-1$. So, how many such swaps are needed to change the exchange matrix into the identity matrix?

Comment: @ChrisLewis And proofs can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/721504/339790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $J_n$ denote the exchange matrix of size $n$. It suffices to show the following:

- $\det(J_1) = 1$
- $\det(J_2) = -1$
- For $n \geq 3$, $\det(J_n) = -\det(J_{n-2})$.

The first two statements are easy to prove directly. For the third statement, proceed as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\det(J_n) &= \det \pmatrix{0&J_{n-2}\\J_2 & 0} 
\\ & = \det\pmatrix{J_2 & 0\\0&J_{n-2}} 
\\ & = \det(J_2)\det(J_{n-2}) = -\det(J_{n-2}).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What properties are you using to prove the third statement?

Comment: One: switching rows of a matrix changes the sign of the determinant. Two: the determinant of the block matrix $\pmatrix{A&0\\0&B}$ is $\det(A)\det(B)$.